# How can I convert string to number in mongoDb using $project in aggregation?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm new mongoDB user, I just want to convert string field value to (int, float or long) to be able to do some comparisons and assign the result to a new field.
I couldn't, I have been trying for hours.
Here's what I want to do:

```
// after doing $match and other projections and want to do last one $project 
// P.S: $X values has been assigned in previous $project
{
    $project:
    {
        xNumAsStr: "$X.NumAsStr",
        xNum: NumberInt("$X.NumAsStr"),
        result: NumberInt("$X.NumAsStr") > 2000 ? "SomeStr" : "AnotherStr"
    }
}
```

For sure what I'm doing is not correct, the main idea is I want to do some calculations and comparisons, I don't know them because will be dynamic (entered by a user in UI).
Is there a way to do it like in SQL world:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHERE (some comparisons and math ops here) THEN 'ResultHere'
         ELSE 'NoResult'
       END
```

**UPDATE**
Is there a way to use JS functions to do what I want ?

Comment: The aggregation framework cannot "cast" values, Nor does it send your language functions along for processing. Unless you really need this for a "lexical sort" i.e "60" is actually greater than "7" but as strings it is not, then you should just be converting the returned results from the database. So do you need it for a "sort" or not? If not, then just accept it as a string and convert in the receiving code. Or of course if you want to "add numbers", then fix the data. Or use mapReduce instead. JavaScript can cast.

Comment: I'll need it for sorting and for calculations, for mapReduce I think I can't use it because I don't have array, I have object.

Comment: All drivers support mapReduce. But the real answer is if you have "strings" that are meant to be numeric, then you fix them rather than trying to code around it.

Comment: The problem is that the value of the fields differ between users inserting the docs and the type of doc it self, sometimes it's string and another is numeric, the user will be able to know and write the suitable equation.

Answer (score 2):

Available since MongoDB v4.0+, there is an aggregation operator [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) that is able to convert a value to a specified type.

Syntax:

```
{
   $convert:
      {
         input: <expression>,
         to: <type expression>,
         onError: <expression>,  // Optional.
         onNull: <expression>    // Optional.
      }
}
```

See also [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/#exp._S_toInt) a syntactical sugar for `$convert` operator.

For your conditional comparison case, you can utilise [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator.